# Give an equation for the curve

Tags: calculus, parametric, parametrization

If I am given the following: "Parameterize the unit circle centred around $(1,2)$" and I find the parameteric equation

$x=1+cos(t)$

$y=2+sin(t)$

and they then ask me to give an equation to the curve, is the equation just $x^2+ y^2=1$ ?

Comment: No, $(1+\cos t)^2+(2+\sin t)^2\ne 1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, but $(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=1$ is true

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot that I had to include the points. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
x-1=\cos t \qquad y-2=\sin t
$$
so, since $\cos^2t +\sin^2t=1$ :
$$
(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=1
$$
is the cartesian equation.